# JUnit gives incorrect answer in NetBeans and doesn't work in terminal

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I have been following the instructions on [this](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started) page and have had no luck. 
When I run

```
java -cp .;junit-4.XX.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest
```

I get
./junit-4.12.jar: ./junit-4.12.jar: cannot execute binary file
./hamcrest-core-1.3.jar: ./hamcrest-core-1.3.jar: cannot execute binary file

I have been searching online for a solution but have had no luck. I may be in over my head here, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you clean and build the project, you will get a .jar file, and then you can try

`java -jar (absolute path to .jar file)`.

Comment: This works, but the test still gives the wrong answer as it does it NetBeans. I am using their given test in the instructions but cannot get it to return a false.

Comment: Make sure you are building the project every time you make a change. If it still doesn't work, check if the code is identical to the instructions.